# Method invocation failed with exception: null: java.lang.IllegalStateException : at AbstractInvocationHandler.java:159

Tags: cxf, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

Am trying to trigger the webservice in my project and am getting below stack trace: the same webservice is wokring fine in jboss 5.1 and Apache CXF : 2.2.12. 2.7.17-redhat-1, but not in jboss eap 6.4 and Apache CXF : 2.7.17-redhat-1

stack trace:

```
JBAS015594: Method invocation failed with exception: null: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.getComponentViewMethod(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:159)
        at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:121)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:177) [jbossws-cxf-server-4.3.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104) [cxf-api-2.7.14.redhat-1.jar:2.7.14.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:237) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.redhat-1.jar:2.7.14.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:69) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.redhat-1.jar:2.7.14.redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:146) [jbossws-cxf-server-4.3.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) [cxf-api-2.7.14.redhat-1.jar:2.7.14.redhat-1]
```

Please help if you get anything on this. thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any exception thrown on webservice side? Did you try to use any HTTP sniffer to see if there is any difference in transport layer?

Comment: @James R. Perkins... I am also facing the same issue. Its working fine in Weblogic but while deploying in Jboss 6.4 its gives me this issue. Can you please suggest me solution if you already found

Comment: My Error is JBAS015594: Method invocation failed with exception: null: java.lang.NullPointerException